# What if the base image delete by others?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-image

For following dockerfile:

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
```

If the maintainer on dockerhub for ubuntu delete the 12.04 tag, any impact for me?
If any impact, how I can avoid?

Answer (score 2):

If the image is deleted from Docker Hub you will not be able to build your image again.

If you are happy to stick with that version, and the licensing allows it, one solution is to copy the the base image into your own [private registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). That way nobody can delete it and you have a reproducible build for as long as you choose to maintain this registry.

Answer (score 0):

There will be another public registry for you. If it is deleted from all the repository. You would get an error that the image not found. 
So I suggest you could do a search with the command `docker search ubuntu:12.04` first and then select an existing one.